# Version of Ruby updated but Rails app still uses its older version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I installed newer version of Ruby (2.5.1) so I get (in my Ubuntu 16.04):

```
me@computer:~$ ruby -v
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux]
```

But when I go to my Rails (4.2.10) app and turn on WEBbrick server, it uses older Ruby version (2.3.1):

```
me@computer:~/Sites/app$ rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.10 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2018-06-29 13:17:35] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2018-06-29 13:17:35] INFO  ruby 2.3.1 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
[2018-06-29 13:17:35] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=6997 port=3000
```

To install newer version of Ruby I was using rbenv. So the command says correctly:

```
me@computer:~/Sites/app$ rbenv version
2.5.1 (set by /home/me/.rbenv/version)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not familiar with rbenv, but have you checked your Gemfile? It should say `ruby '2.3.1'` or something.

Comment: My Gemfile doesn't have any information about Ruby version. Neither "ruby" or '2.3.1'. It starts from: source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '~> 4.2', '>= 4.2.10' ... and after there are only gems.

Comment: What's in your `.ruby-version` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Gemfile below the `source 'https://rubygems.org'` add the **ruby '2.5.1'**
Then do the `bundle install`. If `bundle install` not happen properly just remove the `Gemfile.lock` then do the `bundle install`

Comment: Helped! After that I had to do (in command): 'rbenv rehash' and after 'gem install bundler'. And newer version finally works. Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that removing the `Gemfile.lock` is pretty dangerous. All gems you need will jump to the highest possible value allowed by your `Gemfile`. This could lead to unwanted upgrading of gems.

Comment: For me, I downloaded a repo from my Windows computer at work to my Linux computer at home and my Linux had an older version installed. After reinstalling to the newest version of ruby, the rails server still insisted I was using an old version. Your mention to re-do `bundle install` saved me. After that, it started just fine.